# Binding component prop on input and instance variable

Tags: vue.js

In the following example, I have the vue instance variable "formTerms" that I want to bind to the  component property "abc", which itself is bound to the inputfield in its template. When changing the input's value, I want the instances "formTerms" variable to get that value. However, the code does not seem to work.

JS:

```
Vue.component('terms',{
    model: {
        prop: 'abc',
        event: 'submit',
    },
    props: ['abc'],
    template: '<div><input type="text" name="terms" class="form-control" title="" @change="submit" :value="abc"/></div>',
    methods: {
        submit: function() {
            this.$emit('submit', this.abc);
        }
    }
});
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#id',
    data: {
        formTerms: ''
    },

});
```

HTML:

```
<terms v-model="formTerms"></terms>
```

Comment: Isn't that what the v-model in terms is supposed to do?

Comment: formTerms is an empty String in the instance, initially. I am passing this value to the component via 'v-model=formTerms'. In order to make use of that as a 'model' in the component, it has to be defined as a 'prop' as well, thats what the documentation says.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to bind a v-model to a custom component you have to do it like this

```
Vue.component('terms',{
    props: ['value'],
    template: '<div><input ref="input" type="text" name="terms" class="form-control" title="" @input="$emit('input', $refs.input.value)" :value="value"/></div>'
});
var vm = new Vue({
    el: '#id',
    data: {
        formTerms: ''
    },

});
```

then you can use your component in the parent like you did

```
<terms v-model="formTerms"></terms>
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware of the v-on:input thing

Comment: Unfortunately, I get an Error in v-on handler: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined"

Comment: Have you added the `ref="input"` attribute to the input element?